# Messing with Twitter login using both Fabric and Parse.com

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform, twitter-fabric

I'm so confused. I started using `parse.com`, noted they had useful APIs for logging in with Twitter, and was doing:

```
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, ...)
    }
});
```

So when clicking on `login` (a simple button of mine) I was being shown a floating dialog, and asked to give permissions to **the app I registered on the [Twitter Application Management](https://apps.twitter.com)**.

Then I wanted to have the twitter-designed log-in button, of course, and so subscribed to `io.fabric`, installed Twitter APIs, and put a `<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton/>` element in my layout.

This button **needs no click listener**, because clicking on it brings up a new window where I am asked to give permissions to a **fabric registered app which I wasn't even aware of**, and that I can manage through **[the official Fabric website](https://fabric.io/settings/apps)**.

### So

if I have a `TwitterLoginButton` and also set my `parse.com` click listener on it, I will be asked giving permission to **two different apps** (but these are the same app I'm working on!)

- How to get elegantly out of this mess?
- Is there something I can do to merge the two applications in these two different websites?
- Should I stick to one approach or the other? I really need the user to sign on my `parse.com` database. But if only use `ParseTwitterUtils`, I won't have the login button (right?).
- What is really happening when calling `ParseTwitterUtils.logIn`? Is it logging in the user into Twitter (and so I'll be able to use "share" functions and such), or just fetching user data into the `parse.com` database?

Wrote four questions, but what I'm really asking is what is the most used approach to this.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android  have you looked at that?  Just install it and it will work. Remove the Facebook button at the "builder.config" step and you will  just have the Twitter button which you can overload with another .png